# WPF DataTemplate from another assembly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Is it possible to reference DataTemplate which is located in another assembly in DataTemplateSelector.

Currently I have something like this:

```
public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var element = container as FrameworkElement;

        if (element != null && item != null && item is BrowserBaseViewModel)
        {
            return element.FindResource("BrowserDataTemplate") as DataTemplate;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

But it works only with current assembly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, write in your `app.xaml` a ResourceDictionary "include" so the dictionary can be found in your application.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/MyOtherAssembly;component/MyAssemblyXaml.xaml" />
```

Now your data template will be found, because the resource lookup will look into the app.xaml resources, and find your referenced xaml.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve this dynamically somehow? I am facing a similar situation, but the assembly that contains my data templates is unknown at compile-time, as it will be added at runtime as a plugin.