# How to show UserControl dynamically loaded from outer assembly in MVVM fashion

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls

I'm developing a WPF MVVM application.

MainWindow VM loads a target outer assembly containing a UserControl and its ViewModel.

I want to show this UserControl in my MainWindow View.

I think I should use DataTemplates, but I can't understand how to make them work with dynamically loaded Types. I've no code to show because I've no idea on how to proceed, any suggestion is appreciated.

EDIT: here below the code used to load UC and VM from assembly

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(testProgramPath);
var publicTypes = assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsPublic).ToArray();
TestProgramUserControl = publicTypes.Single(t => t.BaseType.FullName == "System.Windows.Controls.UserControl");
TestProgramUserControlViewModel = publicTypes.Single(t => t.GetCustomAttribute<TestProgramUserControlViewModelAttribute>() != null);
```

I can't make any assumption about UC or its VM, I want to display it in my MainWindow whatever it contains or does. It will be then its duty to communicate via proper messaging with suitable recipients.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WPF DataTemplate from another assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15759529/wpf-datatemplate-from-another-assembly)

Comment: @Sinatr no because assembly is not known at compile time

Comment: Can you show how you load assembly, how you get types and what you want exactly? It's not clear how you want to show `UserControl`, but if data template is defined in that assembly (to show certain type), then you just need to load that data template and set instance of some `ContentControl.Content` to instance of that dynamic type.

Comment: @grandangelo: How is this related to MVVM? If you have a view type and a view model type, you would create an instance of the both and set the `DataContext` of the view instance to an instance of the view model.

Comment: @mm8 is related to MVVM because I'm speaking about view models and views, and I'd like to avoid to do tricks in code behind.

Comment: @grandangelo: Code-behind? Where do you have the code you have posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to advices here, and on SO WPF chat, I solved my problem as follows.

I added a constraint: my outer assembly can contain only one UserControl, and this user control must define a DataTemplate as a resource with a fixed name.
My main VM gets from outer UC the only resource with the aforementioned fixed name.
My main View uses this DataTemplate as ContentTemplate for a ContentPresenter.

Some simplified code for Outer User Control:

```
<UserControl xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="FixedKeyTemplate"
                          DataType="{x:Type local:MyOuterViewModel}">
                <StackPanel>
                    ...
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
</UserControl>
```

Main View Model:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(testProgramPath);
var publicTypes = assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsPublic).ToArray();

Type userControlType = publicTypes.Single(t => t.BaseType.FullName == "System.Windows.Controls.UserControl");
UserControl userControlView = Activator.CreateInstance(userControlType) as UserControl;
DataTemplate userControlDataTemplate = userControlView.Resources["TestProgramGUIDataTemplate"] as DataTemplate;

Type userControlViewModelType = publicTypes.Single(t => t.GetCustomAttribute<UserControlViewModelCustomAttribute>() != null);
object userControlViewModel = Activator.CreateInstance(userControlViewModelType);
```

Main View:

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding UserControlViewModel}"
                  ContentTemplate="{Binding Path=DataContext.UserControlTemplate,
                                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                                                           AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
```

@Andy suggestion is more "professional", but as far as I'm in control of the complete application, and I'm also the only user, I think I can be satisfied by this simpler solution.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestions are a bit long for a comment.

Since you have "no idea" how to go about this here are some suggestions to point you in the right direction.

Managed Extensibility Framework is designed for dynamic discovery for extending applications in the way you describe. They made it for you.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/mef/

As well as putting your view and viewmodel in this assembly, I recommend also putting a datatemplating resourcedictionary in there. You can use this to associate the view type with viewmodel type.
You can use mef or just a naming convention to define what this resource dictionary is.

To make a resource dictionary discoverable by mef you need to add a code behind class for it. You can then apply the correct attribute to that eg:

```
[Export(typeof(ResourceDictionary))]
public partial class ExternalDataTemplateResourceDictionary : ResourceDictionary
{
    public ExternalDataTemplateResourceDictionary ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
 }
```

To connect that class up to your resourcedictionary you use a similar mechanism to that you have probably seen in windows or usercontrols. You use x:Class in it's opening tag:

```
<ResourceDictionary      
       ....
       x:Class="YourProject.ExternalDataTemplateResourceDictionary "
```

When you discover a dll, you load it's contents and merge it's templating resourcedictionary.
The parent view then doesn't need to explicitly know that your specialFoo usercontrol is associated with a superFooViewModel in this dll it's loaded. That merged datatemplate does that using the "standard" viewmodel first datatype association.